# How to add an image to an html file

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

i have a folder named app where my python script is, in this folder there is another folder named templates where my 3 html scripts are, the image i want to display is on the templates folder, the
structure looks like this:

```
app/
```

```
├── app.py
```

```
 └── templates/
```

```
  ├── registro.html
```

```
  ├── registro_exitoso.html
```

```
  ├── contact.html
```

```
  └── logo-inmedi.jpg
```

This is how im displaying the image in the html:

`<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo-inmedi.jpg') }}" class="logo">`

And in the python script i have this:

`app = Flask(__name__) app.static_folder = 'templates/static'`

i have tried displaying the image without the static folder, as well as, using jpg and png

Comment: your image needs to be in a folder named `static/images`. see this answer as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53758128/display-image-on-html-page-using-flask

Answer (score 0):

To display images locally in flask, you need to save them in a folder called `'static/images'` in the `app/` directory. So you can refer to it in the code as `<img src="static/images/logo-inmedi.jpg" class="logo">`